# showing chatlog from sql query node.js socket.io

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

So i have a chatroom i am building [here](http://billischill.ddns.net:8080)and i am storing all of the messages users send in a database and in what chatroom they send it from how could i do something like var query = query the database were chatroom == socket.chatroom

so it would only show messages that corrispond to the chatroom

and how can i display it after the user changes and connects to a new chatroom

here is my server js

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var usernames = {};
var rooms = ['General-Chat','Tech-Chat','Gamer-Chat',"BillIsChill-Underground-Chat","Programer-Chat","Hacker-Chat","Minecraft-Chat","Gta-Chat","Misc-Chat","Current-Events-Chat"];



 app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendfile('index.html');
   //res.sendfile('/login/');
 });
http.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8080');
});

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "messages"
});
function updateLog(){

//this is what i have tried
var log='';
for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
  log += rows[i].username + '    ' + rows[i].message +'<br>';
}
document.getElementById("chatlog-display-div").innerHTML = log;


}
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
    socket.username = username;
    socket.room = 'General-Chat';
    usernames[username] = username;
    socket.join('General-Chat');
    socket.broadcast.to('General-Chat').emit('updatechat', '<b class="servertxt">SERVER: </b>', socket.username + ' has connected to this room' + '<hr>');
    socket.emit('welcomeuser', '<b class="servertxt">SERVER:</b> Welcome ',  socket.username + '<hr>');
    socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, 'room1');
});
socket.on('switchRoom', function(newroom){
  socket.leave(socket.room);
  socket.join(newroom);
  socket.emit('updatechat', '<b class="servertxt"> SERVER </b>', 'you have connected to '+ newroom + '<hr>');
  // sent message to OLD room
  socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', '<b class="servertxt"> SERVER </b>', socket.username+' has left this room <hr>');
  // update socket session room title
  socket.room = newroom;
  socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', '<b class="servertxt"> SERVER </b>', socket.username+' has joined this room <hr>');
  socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, newroom);
});
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });
  socket.on('chat-message', function (usernames, message) {
 console.log('message:', usernames + ': ' + message.text);
 var insert = { roomName: socket.room, username: usernames, message: message.text };
         con.query('INSERT INTO messages SET ?', insert, function(err,res){
          if(err) throw err;
        console.log('Last insert ID:', res.insertId);
      });
     socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit("chat-message", usernames, message);
   });
});
```

and here is my client code

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
  <meta name="description" content="BillIsChill-2.0 BETA"/>
  <meta name="keywords" content="billischill,Bill,is,chill,2.0,billischill-2.0,gamer-chat,BillIsChill-Underground-Chat,BILLISCHILL"/>
  <meta name="author" content="Nik Hendricks">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <title>BillIsChill-2.0</title>
  <link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="http://billischill.ddns.net/billischill-2.0/css/masterStyle.css" />
 <link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="http://billischill.ddns.net/billischill-2.0/css/animate.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="main-header-div">
  <p id="main-header-div-text">BillIsChill-2.0<p>
    <form>
      <input id="main-header-div-search-txtinpt" class="search" placeholder="Search" name="search"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar-controls-div">
  <div id="sidebar-homebutton">
    <div class="sidebar-control-img" id="sidebar-homebutton-img">   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Chatrooms-sidebar-button" class="sidebar-control-button">
  <div class="sidebar-control-img" id="sidebar-chatroombutton-img"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="avatar-sidebar-button" class="sidebar-control-button">
    <div class="sidebar-control-img" id="sidebar-avatarbutton-img"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="chat-rooms-div" class="main-div">
  <div id="rooms"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="chat-box-div" class="main-div">
  <div id="chatlog-display-div"></div>
  <form id="chatform" action="">
  <hr id="chat-box-div-hr">
  <div id="chat-controls-div">
    <input id="chat-box-div-txtinpt" class="big-txtinpt"type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Message">
    <input id="chat-box-div-submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
  </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="online-users-div"><div>

  <script>
    var socket = io();

    socket.on('connect', function() {


//here in the future we are going to check to see if the user is logged in or     not and if he isnt redirect him to the login page

        var user = prompt("What's your name?");
        socket.username = user;
        socket.emit('adduser', user);
    });

    socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
        $('#chatlog-display-div').append(username + data);
    });

    socket.on('welcomeuser', function(data, username){
        jQuery("#chatlog-display-div").append(data + username);
    });

    socket.on('updaterooms', function(rooms, current_room) {
        $('#rooms').empty();
        $.each(rooms, function(key, value) {
            if(value == current_room){
                $('#rooms').append('<div id="chatroom-box"><center>' + value + '<center></div><hr>');
                $("#chatlog-display-div").scrollTop($("#chatlog-display-div").prop("scrollHeight"));
            }
            else {
                $('#rooms').append('<div id="chatroom-box"><center><a id="chatroom-box-link" href="#" onclick="switchRoom(\''+value+'\')">' + value + '</a></center></div><hr>');
                $("#chatlog-display-div").scrollTop($("#chatlog-display-div").prop("scrollHeight"));
            }
         });
    });

    function clearBox(elementID){
        document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "";
    }
    function switchRoom(room){
        socket.emit('switchRoom', room);
    }

    $('form').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //right here is were i started changin it
      //gets the value from the message text feild and sets it as the    message var
      var message = {
        text : $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').val()
      }
      if (message.text.trim().length !== 0) {
        socket.emit('chat-message', socket.username, message);
        //append the message to the chatlog-display-div
        $('#chat-box-div-txtinpt').focus().val('');
        jQuery("#chatlog-display-div").append('<div><b>'+socket.username+':</b>&nbsp'+message.text+'</div><hr>');
        $("#chatlog-display-div").scrollTop($("#chatlog-display-div").prop("scrollHeight"));
      }
    });

     socket.on('chat-message', function (usernames, message) {
     jQuery("#chatlog-display-div").append('<div><b>'+ usernames + ':</b>&nbsp'+message.text+'</div><hr>');
      $("#chatlog-display-div").scrollTop($("#chatlog-display-div").prop("scrollHeight"));
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you ready for some [tests](http://185.3.114.84)? :-)

Comment: Yep im ready hopefully we can figure it out im sure you already know the solution though :)

Comment: So come to the above link, test it and leave your comment

Comment: It woks great you are awesome